# How to run app on genymotion for the first time on android studio

Tags: android, genymotion

I have installed genymotion and created a virtual device and configured it with android studio, when I want to run any app it open the emulator instead of genymotion.

Android studio 1.0.1

Comment: Change your configuration settings.
Select/Run Debug Configuration (android icon on toolbar) -> Edit Configurations  on Target Device  check "show Chooser Dialog"  -> Apply -> OK

Answer (score 3):

It is probably because the run configuration is set to run by default on the emulator.

Go to "Run -> Edit Configurations..."
Then select the run configuration you use for launching your app, and for the "Target Device" choose "Show Chooser dialog".
Save and run, it should show a dialog asking you to select the GenyMotion or the emulator.